# org-mime-htmlize export body only

Tags: org-mime

I am looking for a way to export the html/text body part generated by org-mime-htmlize without the header.

I use notmuch mail for most of my mailing and threading is very important to me, so I want to stay within one thread when replying.
When I send code snippets I use org-mime-htmlize for quick editing.
But currently I have to open an org-mode buffer, htmlize it, select and copy the body part from it and paste it in to my reply mail.

I was wondering if it is possible to **only** export the body part to speed up copying and pasting?

Before doing something with within text searches, I wanted to ask, if there is maybe already a solution out there?

Comment: I use Gnus, there org-mime-htmilize doesn't cause me to lose thread. I'm not sure how'd it do it, since it doesn't modify subject and other fields like from/reply-to etc. Can you explain in more detail the undesired effect you see when you try to run org-mime-htmlize on your email? Also, what about narrowing to region before htmlizing?

Comment: How do you do the htmlization in Gnus?
Basically the process is I mark an org-mode region and use org-mime-htmlize which open up a new mail buffer. However the header is blank, leaving me to fill it in, or copy the message body into my reply mail.

Comment: I just write Org markup inside the mail buffer and then call org-mime-htmlize on it. It knows not to touch the header fields / put the generated HTML in the appropriate tags by creating a multipart message and putting the HTML in the parts with types text/plain and text/html.

Comment: Oh, great that actually works. Never came to my mind to try it like this.
Is this behaviour documented anywhere? I think it might be helpful for people to know. If you put it as an answer, I will accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was looking for the place in the [documentation](http://orgmode.org/worg/org-contrib/org-mime.html) where it might say explicitly how to use it inside email buffers, but it doesn't.  In retrospect you could guess it, since the documentation tells you to add hooks to `mml` mode, but there's still some guesswork involved.  The quote below is from the documentation embedded in `org-mime.el`.  Again, not exactly saying how to use it inside the email buffer, but close.

```
;;; Commentary:

;; WYSWYG, html mime composition using org-mode
;;
;; For mail composed using the orgstruct-mode minor mode, this
;; provides a function for converting all or part of your mail buffer
;; to embedded html as exported by org-mode.  Call `org-mime-htmlize'
;; in a message buffer to convert either the active region or the
;; entire buffer to html.
;;
;; Similarly the `org-mime-org-buffer-htmlize' function can be called
;; from within an org-mode buffer to convert the buffer to html, and
;; package the results into an email handling with appropriate MIME
;; encoding.
;;
;; you might want to bind this to a key with something like the
;; following message-mode binding
;;
;;   (add-hook 'message-mode-hook
;;             (lambda ()
;;               (local-set-key "\C-c\M-o" 'org-mime-htmlize)))
;;
;; and the following org-mode binding
;;
;;   (add-hook 'org-mode-hook
;;             (lambda ()
;;               (local-set-key "\C-c\M-o" 'org-mime-org-buffer-htmlize)))
```

So, basically, you'd add a hook to `message-mode` and call this function using whatever keybinding you assign to it to get the message converted to HTML.

Comment: Great! Thank you. I added three evil-mode keybindings. One to switch to org-mode, one to switch back to message-mode and one for the org-mime-htmlize.  (Apparently it needs to be in message-mode to recognize that it doesn't have to write the header and signature.) Works like a charm.

Comment: After converting the message buffer to org-mode and back to message-mode I get an FCC error. Does this happen to you? (Mail sends fine though.)